# CSV record with spaces is not saving to the database

Tags: csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to save the below kind of CSV records into a DB:

`9,Lambert,Kent D,Senator`

But it is not being saved in DB, the transaction is being rollbacked and giving this error.

```
{"state_senate_district_id"=>"9", "last_name"=>"Lambert", "first_name"=>"Kent D", "tag"=>"Senator"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
["First name should contain only alphabets"]
```

So there is a space in `first_name = "Kent D"`, hence it is not allowing space, so it's not saving to the DB.

Below is the code to parse the CSV:

```
hash = {}
CSV.foreach('Senator.csv', {:headers=>:first_row}) do |line|
hash['state_senate_district_id'] = line[0]
hash['last_name'] = line[1]
hash['first_name'] = line[2]
hash['tag'] = line[3]
puts hash
senator = Senator.new(hash)
unless senator.save(hash)
    err = senator.errors.full_messages
    p err
    File.open("errors", "a") do |csv|
      err.each do |c|
        csv << "\n"
        csv << "||||||"
        csv << [c]
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: try with {:col_sep => ","}

Comment: Please include your `Senator` model, as that's likely where the problem is.

Comment: thank you so much, it's right there is validation in model :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a validation rule in the `Senator` model that is preventing the `first_name` field from having a space. Remove that validation or change it so that it allows spaces.

Comment: thank you so much, it's right there is validation in model :)